# Calculate integral and Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

I'm a beginner in the Fourier series and I can't find the solution to the below integral and relationship with the Fourier series. If

$$f(x)=1+\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\cos(nx)+\frac{1}{n^2}\sin(nx)$$

calculate

$$I=\int^\pi_{-\pi}f(x)(\sin(2.5x)+\cos(2.5x))^2\cos(5x)dx.$$

Any help and hint are much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Simplify out all all the trig in the integrand until you are left with $C_1\cos(ax)+ C_2\sin(bx)$. When you integrate a Fourier series against trig, it kills all the terms except for the terms in resonance aka the terms in the Fourier series that have the same $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I simplify out all the trig and I achieve--> cos(5x) + 0.25*sin(10x). Doesn't this contradict the question? The Fourier series of the question has the same a and b.

Comment: Why would it contradict? If the Fourier series didn't have those $a$ and $b$, then the integral would be zero.

Comment: @NinadMunshi Simplified phrase is  cos(5x) + 0.25*sin(10x) and question is p*cos(nx) + q*sin(nx). Both resonance of the question are 'n' in the integral.

Comment: $n$ is not a variable that actually exists. What is the summation notation short for? Also btw the coefficient for $\sin 10 x$ is not correct